# Documentation about AppScript and ModScript (Serena)

Tags: vbscript, chaiscript

I'm currently working for a bank as an analyst developper. The bank uses SBM from Serena (recently buy back by Micro Focus). The problem is that the scripts are coded in AppScript (VBScript 4.0) and in ModScript (ChaiScript/C++) and I can't find any documentations on the Internet about those two. The only things I found was on the forum of Serena...

Either I look bad, or those languages are not well known.

Maybe someone here got some doc ? Would help me a lot !

I thank you already for the help you will bring me !

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for Modscript and Appscript can be found online through the Documentation portal for MicroFocus/Serena.

Specifically the Composer help guide covers alot of ground for the scripting languages  this is the latest version's guide (11.5) http://help.serena.com/doc_center/sbm/ver11_5/composer/help.html

However, you can switch versions and find plenty of documentation here:
http://help.serena.com/doc_center/doc_center.html#sbm

Additionally there is community dedicated to the Serena-owned products at http://serenacentral.com